# SSAS Visual Totals not work in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I am setting a Role security in SSAS to restrict user to view one member in a dimension. I created a new role called RoleHistory and added Window Server Group called GroupHistory in Membership tab. In Dimension Data tab, I choose one attribute "History (HIS)" and tick "Enable Visual Totals" checkbox to ensure the Grand Total to be displayed correctly.

After setting the Role, I process the Cube and tried to run the result in the SSAS cube browser. It works. Only History (HIS) is shown and Total is 426 for that member. The Grand Total is correct too.

Data shown in Cube browser for that :


Department     Distinct_Students
History (HIS)     426
Grand Total     426

Then, I tried to run the result in Excel by setting up an Analysis Connection. This time, it works partially. It is correct to show History (HIS) in excel. However, the Grand Total is not correct. The Data is shown as this in Excel:

Row Labels     Distinct Students
History (HIS)        426
Grand Total       16,145

Even though I have ticked "Enable Visual Totals" in SSAS, it seems it does not effective in Excel. I am sure my User account is added to Window Server Group - GroupHistory as I can only select History (HIS) in the dimension in Excel.

Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing to check - is your user also an administrator (either in SSAS or on the machine hosting SSAS)? If so it will override more restrictive security settings, including Visual Total settings.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have checked that the user is not an administrator. Besides, the user can only see the History (HIS) attribute from the Dimension, is it an evidence that user is not an administrator? (This is a question as I am not familiar with Windows Servers management.)

Comment: I figured out the problem. Sam is right. I have another role which can access all the Dimensions in the Cube. That's why the Grand Total still shows the total of all departments.

After remove my account from that role, the Visual Totals works correctly then.

Thanks Sam.

Comment: @Terence, I have a similar problem but in my case when enable visual totals it shows correct totals, but it also shows individual rows to the user who is not allowed to see those rows. see my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322961/row-level-security-in-ssas-multidimensional