# enable visual totals in SSAS multidimensional not giving desired output

Tags: ssas

We have implemented row level security in our SSAS database. In our business case we have property level security and account level security. In property level security user should be able to see data for only those properties which are assigned to him, and in Account Level security a user should be able to see data of only those accounts for which he is authorized to access.

After security implementation we noticed a problem due account level security implementation, users were not able to see correct totals for those hierarchies which were having some accounts which were not accessible to the user due to security restriction. e.g. if a user is head of purchase department he is having access to sales accounts only, but when he browse cube for net profit he is seeing wrong net profit, as the net profit only calculates based on sales department accounts.

I want to know for the possible solution to sort out this issue.

Comment: If you are assigning your security model via roles, have you enabled Visual Totals on the role itself? Without this, it will continue to show the proper, unfiltered total.

Comment: when I enable visual totals on the role it shows correct totals, but also shows all underlying accounts even though they are not accessible to him

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - did someone find a solution?
also apologies for digging this out of thegraveyard